# Div's are overlapping each other vertically (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have three different divs that should be displaying one after the other, but they just jump right up to each other on the webpage. Here is the code for all of them:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="top-section">
  <center>
    <div class="container" style="margin-top:150px;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="top-title">
          <h1>Introducing 10/40 Academy.</h1>
          <h3>An affordable entrepreneurship course that can double as high school credit.</h3>
          <img src="/Man_iPhone_Desk.jpg" style="height:300px;margin:30px;border-radius:4px;" class="raised hidden-xs" /><br>
          <a href="#showVideo" data-toggle="tab" class="halfraised btn btn-primary hidden-xs">Watch Video&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span></a>
          <h3 class="hidden-sm hidden-xs" style="letter-spacing:2px;margin-top:0px;">SCROLL DOWN</h3>
          <h1 class="hidden-sm hidden-xs" style="font-weight:100;font-size:30px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </center>
</div>

<div class="begin-tour">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top:50px;">
        <h2>Interested in small business?</h2>
        <h2>We're here to help.</h2>
        <p>
          Paragraph
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <center>
          <img width="70%" src="/MacImageBase.png" />
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="qualif">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2>Header here</h2>
        <h2>Header</h2>
        <p>
          some text
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The best way to explain what happens is through a photo.

[image]

Comment: FYI the `<center>` element doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I've added the 3 divs into the bootstrap container, took out center(it is not used anymore or supported by HTML5), put each div as a 12 column row(col-md-12 class) so they show up one after the other like you wanted:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="top-section  col-md-12">
      <div class="container" style="margin-top:150px;">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="top-title">
            <h1>Introducing 10/40 Academy.</h1>
            <h3>An affordable entrepreneurship course that can double as high school credit.</h3>
            <img src="/Man_iPhone_Desk.jpg" style="height:300px;margin:30px;border-radius:4px;" class="raised hidden-xs" /><br>
            <a href="#showVideo" data-toggle="tab" class="halfraised btn btn-primary hidden-xs">Watch Video&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span></a>
            <h3 class="hidden-sm hidden-xs" style="letter-spacing:2px;margin-top:0px;">SCROLL DOWN</h3>
            <h1 class="hidden-sm hidden-xs" style="font-weight:100;font-size:30px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="begin-tour col-md-12">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top:50px;">
            <h2>Interested in small business?</h2>
            <h2>We're here to help.</h2>
            <p>
              Paragraph
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <center>
              <img width="70%" src="/MacImageBase.png" />
            </center>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="qualif col-md-12">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>Header here</h2>
            <h2>Header</h2>
            <p>some text</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/8CPnGgLFGLfmh7ekNgKA?p=preview) so you can see it.

Please let me know if this helps. I didn't see your image until now so I hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not change anything. I am still encountering the same problem.

Comment: Do you have a link to the live site? Ill delete the answer once i get to a computer.

Comment: It's currently in a development environment, so I cannot supply a direct link.